# Empty item selected from editable autocomplete Jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, autocomplete, jcombobox

I have a problem with jcombobox when i try to select an item from autocomplete JcomboBox , this is the Jcombobox i created and filled from sqlite database with actionListener :

So what i try to do is to write the first lettre and it will be completed automatically and than with jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt); i will get linked data from sqlite database and add it to  Label

```
        jXLabel2.setText(con.getData()[0][0]);
        jXTextField1.setText(con.getData()[0][1]);
```

when i write a first letter of an item it give me this error

```
Opened database successfully
Records created successfully
SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTR FROM Articles WHERE Designation = ''
0

SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Designation = ''
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at gestionstocktaza.ModArticles.jComboBox2ActionPerformed(ModArticles.java:222)
```

but if i didn't use con.getData()[0][0]) or con.getData()[0][1]) it didn't return any error
and data will be selected normally , also when u use these two in a 'FOR Statemet' it work fine

```
   for(int i=0;i<da.length;i++){
       jXLabel2.setText(da[i][0]);      
       jXTextField1.setText(da[i][1]);      
      }
```

i don't know what is the problem with method return a two dimensional table of string getData

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. related: if that's the swingx autocomplete, you would better tag it as such (the exact nature of your database is probably not really relevant?) Also, consider to post a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: normally the problem related to swing component not with swingx component (i can change it and problem still exist )  , also the queries are alright i already test it , and for SSCCE i thinks that posting problem shortly can't be useful  , tnx for replying

Comment: i don't know what is the problem with method return a two dimensional table of string getData ----- (I see in your code you have used one for loop array try to use two 2 for loop and tell me what happened)

Comment: when i use the loop the code work fine and i can get the selected item  then  the data is returned correctly but when i use the method getdata without loop it give me error

Comment: -1 for refusing a SSCCE (which is the _only_ way to see what's wrong in _your_ code)

Comment: it's edited now , maybe it's not necessary to give that -1 :)

Comment: don't see a SSCCE, google for the acronym if you don't know it :-)

Comment: i don't know how to do this SSCCE a you want , i describe my problem very shortly and clearly , so i think that any other thing will be not useful am i right ;)

Comment: no, you are wrong ;-) But your choice, obviously, good luck!

Comment: no, I don't waste time with chatting about obvious facts ;-)

Comment: i just clicked accidently : automatically move this discussion to chat?

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the connection before addActionListener to your ComboBox

```
 con.CloseDB();

 jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
{
 public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {
    jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
   }
  });
```

Comment: and i re-opened it again in  the method  jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
it's not the error :)

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTR FROM Articles WHERE Designation = '"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()+"'",
            "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Designation = '"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()+"'"); Have you checked this query in your Database

Comment: it work fine  brother , the problem is related to the autocomplete Jcombobox when i try to get selected item it return an empty String like this '' so when it integrated in query the results are not as expected , i hope that the problem is clear

Comment: i don't know what is the problem with method return a two dimensional table of string getData ----- (I see in your code you have used one for loop array try to use two 2 for loop and tell me what happened)